# Why did the Surface Go 2 not charge over USB?

Tags: laptop, usb-c, charging

**TLDR:**

1. brand new Microsoft Surface Go 2
2. Ravpower smart 6-port USB charger with 60W output (6 × 2.4A) ([similar item](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Charger-Charging-Multiple-Technology-Smartphones-White/dp/B098F8FL8B))
3. Anker USB cable
4. plugged in over night, not in use
5. battery at 4% in the morning -- **why??**

**QUESTION:**
What did I do wrong here? What is the missing link?

**DETAILS:**

1. Child received a Surface Go 2 from school yesterday.
2. School recommended that parents follow certain steps (add local admin user, change child account type to standard). I did so in the evening.
3. Child had the manufacturer charger in the bedroom, so I plugged the Surface into the USB charger in the living room: we use this charger for all our devices, works just fine, and tonight no other devices were attached. The Surface was not on, so I guess it counts as stand-by mode. I haven't looked into the power settings of the device yet to see when it goes into hibernation etc. but in the morning it was definitely hibernated.
4. The Surface has an USB C port just like all our phones, and the charger provides lots of power, so I fully expected this to work. Well, it did not, and I can't figure out why not!
5. According to Microsoft help pages, the Surface can be charged via the USB-C port; it does not have to be via the proprietary connector. (F*ck them for putting that on a 2022 device, by the way!)
6. According to Microsoft help pages, the Surface requires 15W input power, so our 60W charger provides more than enough.
7. The Surface can even be charged on a plain ol' phone charger! ([source](https://surfacetip.com/surface-go-usb-c-charging/#how-to-charge-surface-go-with-usb-c))
8. We use short Anker USB cables so I feel the cable itself is not at fault; Samsung phones don't like cheap cables, but these are fine.
9. I do not understand all the different charging standards; "fast charge", "iSmart", "IQ", "QC", "PD", ... whatever happened to *standards?* ([article](https://www.dignited.com/70202/ankers-poweriq-vs-quick-charge-vs-power-delivery-what-are-the-differences/))

Comment: Your article claiming the Go can be charged via any old USB C power is not for the Go2. At any rate from sources I've seen you need to have completely shut down the Go for charging to work, and it will be far slower than using the proper charger or a PD charger. It may be that in order to simplify the power circuitry and remove points of inefficiency they removed the ability to charge from 5V sources.  PD chargers are cheaper and far more prevalent than they were so may have considered it a worthwhile removal.

Comment: I have added some notes on USB-C Charging support directly from Microsoft to my answer. Other chargers *might* work, but what I've said is what Microsoft recommend and support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phone USB C charger is not the same as a laptop USB C charger.

Phone USB-C chargers are generally limited to a 9V output. Depending on the device and battery configuration that may not be enough. Many laptops have 12-14V batteries and 9V simply is not enough.

What you need is a USB-C Power Delivery (PD) charger. These often have power ratings of 65 or 100W of power and can output a range of voltages between 5V and 20V depending on what the laptop or phone asks for.

That you have a random 60W charger is not enough. It needs to be a PD charger. That is a standard modern power delivery charger, not something claiming to be "smart". QC is a power delivery method for phones up to 9V and (I believe) 25 or 45w, still not a high enough voltage. A 4 port 60W QC/iSmart/IQ charger is NOT a PD charger, it is a phone charger. That "60W" is also a total put put across all the ports, no single port is likely to be able to put out the whole 60W alone. A PD charger claiming 65W *will* put out 65W if required by the device being charged.

PD can, in theory, charge any current device on the market. It contains more smart design than previous chargers which were only really intended to charge phones. It is what came along when we started putting USB-C on laptops rather than just phones.

For your question of "what happened to standards?" They are all standards that have come up and been replaced over time. I refer you to [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/927/)

It does appear that a "fast charger" (iQ, QC, iSmart, etc) is not enough for the Go devices.

From [Microsoft: USB-C and Fast Charging for Surface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/usb-c-and-fast-charging-for-surface-d320ab19-e4ed-c36d-7458-7d7aec69d34a)

> #### Fast Charging
>
> If your device has a USB-C port, it **can** also support Fast Charging. **Some Microsoft Surface devices support Fast Charging,**

Implying that not all devices have been set up to accept power from 9V "fast" chargers.

It carries on in the notes

> - For Surface Go, Surface Go 2, Surface Go 3, and Surface Laptop SE, **you’ll need to buy a different power supply or USB Type-C PD charger rated at 60W or higher.**

So anything other that a USB-C PD charger may not work and is unsupported.